# Group data in intervals

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to group data in intervals of 15 (or X) minutes in sql.

For example, i have the next scenario.

[image]

The result that i expect to obtain is

[image]

I tried using Lag function but i dont get what i want, because it add interval to each row and continues grouping.

Thanks in advance and apologies for my bad english.

Comment: Please define what you mean by interval.  It is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the intervals to be calendar based -- i.e. four per hour starting at 0, 15, 30, and 45 minutes, then you can use:

```
select id, min(begin_date), max(begin_date)
from t
group by id, convert(date, begin_date),
         datepart(hour, begin_date), datepart(minute, begin_date) / 15;
```

Note that begin date and end date have the same value, so I just used `begin_date` in this answer.

Comment: No, i need to group the rows that fits in that interval. Keeping the original begin_date and end_date